# How to build flink kafka producer with exactly once behavior?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, producer, exactly-once

I have a simple flink application which consumes alerts from one topic(kafka) and publishes to a new topic(kafka).

I have set the exactly once guarantee for data sink. But, my consumer does not consume that data when I set such guarantees over the sink.

Here are the versions -
JVM version - jdk-11
Flink - 1.15.2

Producer -

```
        KafkaSink<String> mySink = KafkaSink.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
                .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
                .setTransactionalIdPrefix("Msg_Offset_MGMG_Tx_2")
                .setKafkaProducerConfig(producerConfig)             
                .setRecordSerializer(new OffsetSerializer("MySink"))                
                .build();
```

I tried passing below properties in producer -

```
Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 600000);
producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
```

Consumer -

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("commit.offsets.on.checkpoint", "true");
        prop.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        
        KafkaSource<Long> dataSource = KafkaSource.<Long>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
                .setTopics("Alerts")
                .setGroupId("alertss-1")
                .setProperties(prop)
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setClientIdPrefix("Alerts_01_temp_2")              
                .setDeserializer("mycustomSerializer")
                .build();
```

However, when I run this, my sink fails to push any record even though there are messages present in data source.
But, when I remove below lines from data sink it works -

```
setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
                .setTransactionalIdPrefix("Msg_Offset_MGMG_Tx_2")
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doint wrong?

Comment: There are two things I can see as an issue:
1. Have you enabled checkpointing? If not, that's a requirement for exactly-once to work
2. You need to check the value of `transaction.max.timeout.ms` setting at your Kafka broker and pass in a producer property `transaction.timeout.ms` which has a lower value then `transaction.max.timeout.ms`

Comment: Yes, we have checkpointing enabled.
Added the settings you mentioned. It's working.
We also added 
`transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1`  and  
`transaction.state.log.min.isr=1`
to our kafka broker. This enabled the transaction support to the broker. Its a staging env broker that's why we have set the replication and min isr to 1.